# Show icon of its tab

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an api of tab which has name of tab, id of the tab and id of the icon (its a foreign key). I want to show icon of its tab but how can i show when api is designed in such a way.

**api/tab**

```
[
{
    "id": 114,
    "name": "analytics",
    "icon": 2,
},
{
    "id": 127,
    "name": "share",
    "icon": 2,
}
```

]

**api/icon**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "computer",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "insert-photo",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "account-circle",
    }
]
```

**header.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchTabs();
  }

  render() {
    const tabs = _.map(this.props.tabs.tabs, (tab) =>
          <span className="tab" key={tab.id}>
            <a href="">{tab.name}</a>
          </span>
    );

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    fetchIcon: state.fetchIcon,
    tabs: state.tabs,
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    fetchTabs,
  }, dispatch);
}
```

Help me on how to show icon of the tab as they are linked with id?

Error screenshot

when using

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    fetchIcon: state.fetchIcon,
    tabs: state.tabs.map(tab => ({
        ...tab, icon: state.fetchIcon.find(icon =>
            icon.id === tab.icon)
        ).name
    }),
    tabsPost: state.tabsPost
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can un-normalize data in `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tabs: state.tabs.map(tab => ({
        ...tab,
        icon: state.icons.find(icon => 
            icon.id === tab.icon
        ).name
    })
})
```

Now `tab.icon` will be either `computer`, `insert-photo` or `account-circle` in your component.

Edit: after discussion, we have come up with the following code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        tabs: state.tabs.tabs.map(tab => {
            const icon = state.deviceEventOption.find(icon => Number(icon.id) === tab.icon);
            return {
                ...tab,
                icon: icon && icon.name
            };
        })
    };
};
```

Comment: i get error on .name part as unexpected token. const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    fetchIcon: state.fetchIcon,
    tabs: state.tabs.map(tab => ({
        ...tab,
        icon: state.fetchIcons.find(icon => 
            icon.id === tab.icon)
        ).name
    })
    tabsPost: state.tabsPost
});

Comment: that means it could't find an icon with the given id.

Comment: Now the error is shown at the last line of the code on }) as unexpected token.

Comment: This code removed the error but got another error state.tabs.map is not a function const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    fetchIcon: state.fetchIcon,
    tabs: state.tabs.map(tab => ({
            ...tab,
            icon: state.fetchIcon.find(icon =>
                icon.id === tab.icon
            ).name
        })
),
tabsPost: state.tabsPost
 });

Comment: I cannot help resolve all of your issues. You should learn what each error message means. The last error you mention means `state.tabs` does not have a function called `map` which means it is not an array but something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125784/discussion-between-learner-and-mostruash).